# How to express this sentence in another way?

Tags: american-english

I have a sentence:

The covariance across neighboring elements is not informative about the cognitive function under examination.

I want to express this in another way. Please give me a help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This reads as statistical mumbo-jumbo. There are too many unknowns in the sentence to allow us to answer with any certainty. Are the "neighbouring elements" each a series of measurements? Were the measurements in some sense simultaneous? Might they be expected to share to some extent a common cause? Do they relate to the cognitive function? If the answer to all these is yes, we normally talk about covariance of one set "with" another set rather than "across". The sentence gives no indication of which, if either, of the elements relates to the "cognitive function".

The phrase "under examination" adds nothing; if we were not examining it, it would not be the object of the sentence, so we already know that it is under examination.

All I get from the sentence is "We measured two things and their relationship tells us nothing about some other thing".